# How can one find the name of an old arcade game without an image or sound bite?

Tags: discussion, game-identification

Without an image or sound bite how would one find out the name of an old coin-op arcade game made before the early 90's?

There does not seem to be a tag for coin op games and you can only use the [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) tag if you have media of the game in action.

Comment: You could try [/r/tipofmyjoystick](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/), but there isn't really anywhere in the SE network to try.

Comment: It's worth noting that if your game was science fictional or fantastical you can ask over on [scifi.se]. We accept `[story-identification] [video-games]` questions and even have a [specific guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11995/58193) for them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without an artifact from the game itself, asking a game identification question was decided to be off-topic for Arqade. In other words, one wouldn't find out the name of an old coin-op arcade game made before the early 90s here, on Arqade.

Not every possible gaming-related question can be asked here, as the Q&A format of every site in the Stack Exchange network doesn't work well with every possible question. Some questions simply are not a good fit for the system and should not be asked here.

Answer (score 9):

Our sister site [Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) welcomes both [game identification questions](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) (as long as they're written for 'old' computers) as well as [questions about arcade games and hardware](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcade). As always with identification questions, please add as much detail as you can remember and think is relevant.

Comment: The [sci-fi/fantasy stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) also allows game identification questions, as long as the topic of the game could reasonably fall under "sci-fi" or "fantasy"... which fortunately(?) applies to nearly every game.